# How to Remove value from an array using another array with multiple values?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array Array1 and Array2 and I need to remove Array2 value from Array1 I show my both the Array here.

In Array1 I have utype_id is 11 and 14 and I need to remove this id record from Array2 so how can I do it can you please help me?

```
Array1(

    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 22
            [accessid] => 2
            [utype_id] => 11
            [discount] => 3434
            [published] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 23
            [accessid] => 2
            [utype_id] => 14
            [discount] => 2
            [published] => 1
        )
)


Array2
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 9
            [type_name] => Admin
            [description] => admin
            [published] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 10
            [type_name] => Senior sales
            [description] => senior sales
            [published] => 0
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 11
            [type_name] => junior sales
            [description] => junior
            [published] => 1
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 14
            [type_name] => dealer
            [description] => dealer
            [published] => 0
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 15
            [type_name] => fgdg
            [description] => dfg
            [published] => 1
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 16
            [type_name] => fgdfg
            [description] => fgdfg
            [published] => 0
        )

)
```

I didn't get any solution for this. I need only 9,10,15,16 Record id from Array2.

Comment: Please show what have you tried so far.

Comment: $diff = array_diff($array2, $array1);

Comment: none of the items in the one array are in the other

Comment: Extract values from first array, then iterate or filter second array according to extracted values.

Comment: arrays of objects make it harder, no array_column :(

Comment: Show your coding attempt **in the question** not as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, extract `utype_id`s from first array, make them **keys** to speed up search:

```
$utype_ids = [];
foreach ($array1 as $item) {
    $utype_ids[$item->utype_id] = 1;
}
```

Then, filter second array using `$utype_ids`:

```
$filtered_array = array_filter(
    $array2, 
    function($v) use ($utype_ids) {
        return !isset($utype_ids[$v->id]);
    }
);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/i2heV

Answer (score 3):

Just for entertainment purposes (and I was feeling a bit left out :( ).  Index both arrays by the ID (need php 7+ for `array_column()` to support objects as input) and then `array_diff_key()` to remove any from the second array...

```
print_r(array_diff_key(array_column($array2, null, "id"), 
                  array_column($array1, null, "utype_id")));
```

I would like to say that a `foreach()` solution is faster than this, just wanted to join in and post some original content.

Answer (score 1):

Use nested loops to perform the qualifying checks.  Use a `break` as a matter of best practice to avoid unnecessary iterations.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/KE4QK))

```
$blacklist = [
    (object)["id" => 22,"accessid" => 2, "utype_id" => 11, "discount" => 3434, "published" => 1],
    (object)["id" => 23,"accessid" => 2, "utype_id" => 14, "discount" => 2, "published" => 1]
];

$rows = [
    (object)["id" => 9, "type_name" => "Admin", "description" => "admin", "published" => 0],
    (object)["id" => 10, "type_name" => "Senior sales", "description" => "senior sales", "published" => 0],
    (object)["id" => 11, "type_name" => "junior sales", "description" => "junior sales", "published" => 1],
    (object)["id" => 14, "type_name" => "dealer", "description" => "dealer", "published" => 0],
    (object)["id" => 15, "type_name" => "fgdg", "description" => "dfg", "published" => 1],
    (object)["id" => 16, "type_name" => "fgdfg", "description" => "fgdfg", "published" => 0]
];

foreach ($blacklist as $disqualifier) {                 // iterate the blacklist
    foreach ($rows as $index => $row) {                 // iterate the list to be checked
        if ($row->id === $disqualifier->utype_id) {     // if row should be disqualified
            unset($rows[$index]);                       // remove the row
            break;                                      // stop checking the $rows for this $disqualifier
        }
    }
}

var_export($rows);
```

...if you need the output to be reindexed, you can call `array_values($rows)`.

If these arrays of objects are coming from a database table, you should be improving your query to do this filtration process in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use..

```
$arr1ids = array();
foreach($array1 as $val1){
    $arr1ids[] = $val1->utype_id;
}

$resArr = array();
foreach($array2 as $val2){
    if(!in_array($val2->utype_id,$arr1ids)){
       $resArr[] = $val2;
    }  
}

print_r($resArr);
```

Comment: Code only answer are low-value on StackOverflow